# Insert Overwrite is failing on "BigInteger would overflow supported range" in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, sql-insert, databricks

When running an Insert Overwrite in Databricks like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE my_target_table SELECT * FROM my_source_table
```

I get the error:

```
Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Looking through the stack trace, I see a caused by clause:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger would overflow supported range
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have a type mismatch.

Like any other insert statement, you must make sure that the order and type of columns in your select statement match the order and type of the columns in the table you're inserting into.

Unlike most modern RDBMS's, however, this error won't tell you explicitly which column is causing the problem, so the easiest thing to do for large inserts is to convert the select portion of your insert statement into a temporary view and then print the schemas of both the temporary view and the table you're trying to insert into.

Create the view:

```
%sql
--INSERT OVERWRITE your_target_table
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW temp_schema_test AS
SELECT * FROM your_source_table
```

Then print the two schemas:

```
%python
spark.table('your_target_table').printSchema()
```

and

```
%python
spark.table('your_source_table').printSchema()
```

They'll output two lists that might look like this:

> root
>
> |-- DEFAULT_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
>
> |-- DEFAULT_LOCATION: string (nullable = true)
>
> |-- NEW_ID: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
>
> |-- NEW_RECEIPT_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
>
> |-- NEW_REQUEST_ID: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)

and this

> root
>
> |-- INTVW_DT: timestamp (nullable = true)
>
> |-- CURR_LCTN: string (nullable = true)
>
> |-- CASE_IDENTIFIER: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
>
> |-- REQUEST_ID: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
>
> |-- RECEIPT_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)

You'll notice that in my example, the last two rows of the first output are string and decimal, and the second output reverses that for a decimal and string.  This is a simple case of inserting with the wrong column order.  In your case, make sure that regardless of the column names, the types are compatible with each other.